# The ? Operator in PHP / Isset inline if statements? (What exactly does this line do?)

Tags: php, variables, web, inline

```
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : null;
```

Im a little unsure what the above line does? I have some vague ideas (and I know what GET does etc) but I have never come across the `:` "operator"(?) or the `?` "operator" (?).

Thanks very much.

Comment: It's called the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 1):

it is a short syntax of writing

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    $action = $_GET['action']
}else{
    $action = null;
}
```

That means you check a condition before ? mark, if result is true, you execute the part between ? and :
But if condition check returns false, you execute the part after :

Comment: Thanks! Surely it would already be nulled? If it wasnt set that is?

Comment: If it was not set anywhere and if you are using strict PHP mode which I will recommend while you are learning it, then trying to access a variable which is not set already will generate a warning that you are trying to access a variable that doesn't exist. The best way is to always declare a variable before using it.

Answer (score 0):

This means simply..

```
if(isset($_GET['action']))
   $action = $_GET['action'];
else
   $action = null;
```